# Converting external pivot to internal and vice versa

Tags: excel, pivot-table, vba

Excel's UI doesn't allow changing a Pivot table that uses an external data source into a Pivot table that's based on a Table/Range, and vice versa. Is there any way to code it in? How about at least a way to "borrow" all the rows, fields, calculated fields, formats, etc. from one Pivot table to another despite their different types of data sources?

If Pivot #1 uses SQL and Pivot #2 uses a range, then I've tried `ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).PivotTables(1).CacheIndex = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).PivotTables(2).CacheIndex` but got:

> Run-time error '1004':
>
> Application-defined or object-defined error

[image]

Comment: Same Issue.No Solution until now